# Which text animation is this?

Tags: animation

I guess it is an After Effect text animation. Starts at 00:13

I did search a lot here, but did not found it: https://motionarray.com/browse/after-effects-templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a template to do this.

The font is a variation of Zolina according to WhatTheFont:
https://www.myfonts.com/products/bold-zolina-7192

The animation is a series of masks revealing the text, and a stylised dot on the letter "i".  The dot on the "i" is then rotated.

Enter your text on a layer.
Make a new shape layer above it, and draw some paths such that the text is obscured. It might be easier to use a different colour, so you can check you have fully obscured the original text with your paths.

Add a trim path to your shape layers, and animated the end of the trim paths, to make the shape layers grow over time.  You could trim all the paths at the same time, or animate them one by one:

[image: grab1]

Then set your text layer to be a Track Matte, using the shape layer you created above it:

[image: grab2]

Do this for all your letters.

Then after that, make a new shape layer for the dot on the "i", and animate it like this - note the position of the anchor point to make the rotation move appropriately:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is a comprehensive help, thanks :)